# Void Or Other Result In DDD Operation

Tags: domain-driven-design

If this is basic question sorry , but anyway it is a question .

i am doing domain driven design , i know about RootAggreegate , 
Anemic model , Rich Model , Domain Services , and ...

but still when it come to adding or updating a model 
i dont know what pattern it makes sense  to use`? 
should i retun void , or should i return an object of operation result .

```
class operationResult {
public List<string> ErrorMessages {get;set;}
public OperationStateEnum Status {get;set;}
}

void addBook(book)
```

or

```
operationResult addBook(book)
```

Answer (score 6):

If your addBook method is designed so that it will always succeed, a void is preferred. If your method does validation on book, then returning a result is better then handling it with exceptions.

In my opinion, exceptions should be used for exceptional situations only; if a database or webservice is down, throw an exception, but if the title should be unique and it isn't, I would not throw an exception but return a result.

This sums it up nicely:

The method is a command and it can’t fail:

```
public void Save(Customer customer)
```

The method is a query and it can’t fail:

```
public Customer GetById(long id)
```

The method is a command and it can fail:

```
public Result Save(Customer customer)
```

The method is a query and it can fail

```
public Result<Customer> GetById(long id)
```

Source: https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2015/03/20/functional-c-handling-failures-input-errors/

Further reading: https://martinfowler.com/articles/replaceThrowWithNotification.html

Answer (score 4):

The prevailing idiom in object-oriented languages is to return `void`.

The reason being, that callers expect methods to be composable through sequencing, that is, writing them after each other, separated by semicolon (`;`). It would be just be too much repetitive work to have a condition after each method invocation to check whether it succeeded or not (just look at C). That's why there are `Exception`s.

So make it `void`, and throw an `Exception` if there is something wrong, otherwise the caller should assume the operation succeeded.