# Best way to return multiple results from a function in C#

Tags: c#

We have function `DoStuff`. It can return `Stuff` or `Error`. What is the cleanest way to do this in C#? I know that it's best to throw in error case, but it has its own downsides. Also consider case where there are 2 logically different results, which are not errors. what then?

Important for me is that code is readable and robust (i.e. no weird cases when someone can return both success and result by mistake etc.).

Solutions I've found so far:

##### 1. Throw an exception

```
 Stuff DoStuff() { throw new Error(errorCode); }
```

Pros:

1. Easy to add new cases
2. Can pass through multiple layers without altering other code

Cons

1. Can be swallowed by accident
2. You need to inspect function body or spec to see how it fails
3. You need to define additional exception type which is nasty and takes lots of code to do properly

##### 2. Use a container object

```
class DoStuffResult() {
    DoStuffResult(Stuff success) {...}
    DoStuffResult(Error failure) {...}
    public Success? {get;}
    public Error? {get;}
}


// Consumer
var result = DoStuff();
if (doStuffResult.Success != null) {
   Process(result.Success);
}
else {
   ReportError(result.Error);
}
```

Pros:

1. Easy to see what may be there by inspecting container class definition

Cons:

1. There are both `Success` and `Error` properties on single object.
2. What happens when success returns null? You need enum and complexity increases

##### 3. Pattern matching

```
interface IDoStuffResult {};
IDoStuffResult DoStuff() {
    if (x) { return new Success(); }
    else { return new Error(); };
}

// customer
DoStuff() switch { 
   Success success -> Process(success),
   Error error -> Report(error),
   _ -> throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException()
};
```

Pros:

1. Cleanest code to read and write

Cons:

1. Extra marker interface required
2. More than two possible results visible
3. It's not obvious how many possible results are there

Which solution is most readable and easiest to maintain?

Comment: There is similar question focusing on exceptions https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/250518/what-is-a-good-design-for-a-method-that-can-return-several-logically-different-r
But I also wonder about more broad cases, not only exceptions.

Comment: I think the example using exceptions conflates the point of the question. If you need exceptions, use exceptions. If you need multiple unrelated return types, the specific use-case may be relevant. Sometimes a container makes sense. Sometimes it makes sense to extract common denominators into an interface. And sometimes it just makes sense to go back to the whiteboard.

Comment: I prefer a Result<T> for this scenario. See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/381673/320517

Comment: I disagree with all the cons you attribute to exceptions. They can't be swallowed by accident, one has to deliberately write a catch all clause for that to happen, something CodeAnalysis will warn you about. Inspection of code to see what went wrong is not needed as you will pack all there is to know into the exception. Finally, creating new exception types is trivial. You do one properly (which will be readily available on the internet) and use that as a template to create your own.

Comment: Can you clarify your question, please? In your title, you ask about returning *multiple results*, whereas in your question body, you consider returning multiple results "a mistake" ("no weird cases when someone can return both success and result by mistake"). So, which is it: do you want to return multiple results, or don't you want to return multiple results?

Comment: You can see response with tuples below. In that case someone can return both `Success` and `Error` in that tuple, however I would like to be able to return either of them, but not both.

For instance exception satisfies this, becuase you cannot return and throw at same time, so does DoStuffResult because you can use one constructor at time, and so does pattern matching, because you can have only one result.

Comment: I posted an answer to a similar question here, it uses empty interfaces to create Union Types in C# - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/409471/how-to-design-a-statically-typed-rest-api-client/409889?noredirect=1#comment902882_409889

Answer (score 3):

> Which solution is most readable and easiest to maintain?

As usual, the one that eliminates the problem in the first place.

For C#, that tends to mean designing the code so that methods only have one (non-exceptional) return type. Sometimes that means a Result type that can be queried. It should not be exceptions that are not exceptional, or implementations of interfaces that violate LSP. Most times though, a simple design change can eliminate the need for this altogether.

Answer (score 1):

I like very much your pattern matching approach.

---

A pattern often used is the `Try..` method returning a bool indicating the success and an `out` parameter returning the result

```cs
public bool TryDoStuff(out Stuff result)
{
    do_something();
    if (success) {
        result = some_value;
        return true;
    } else {
        result = default;
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can use it like this

```cs
if (TryDoStruff(out var result)) {
    consume_result();
} else {
    handle_error();
}
```

You can add more `out` parameters if required. E.g. if two kinds of result objects are required:

```cs
public bool TryDoStuff(out Stuff result, out Error error)
{
    do_something();
    if (success) {
        result = some_value;
        error = default;
        return true;
    } else {
        result = default;
        error = error_object;
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

A new possibility arises with the introduction of the value tuples

```cs
public (bool success, Stuff result) DoStuff()
{
    do_something();
    if (success) {
        return (true, some_value);
    } else {
        return (false, default);
    }
}
```

You can use it like this

```cs
var (success, result) = DoStuff();
```

Here also, you can extend it to return two different (or more) objects, where only one will not have the default value (`null`). The `bool` value is not necessarily required, as you can test which object is not null. You can also test the result with pattern matching.

Comment: Tuples are arguably "the wrong way round", however. What you want is a *sum type*, but tuples are *product types*. They are exactly the dual of what you need.

Comment: Yes, what we need is a sum or discriminated union or [Tagged union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) type which does not exist in C#.

Comment: We can add a tagged-union.  To sketch it: `public abstract class Result<T> { public abstract bool IsSuccess { get; } protected Result() { } public static Result<T> New_Success( T resultValue ) { return SuccessResult<T>.New(resultValue); } public static Result<T> New_Fail( ) { return FailResult<T>.New(); } } public class SuccessResult<T> : Result<T> { public override bool IsSuccess { get { return true; } } public T ResultValue { get; private set; } protected SuccessResult() { }` [...]

Comment: [...] `public static SuccessResult<T> New( T resultValue ) { var toReturn = new SuccessResult<T>(); toReturn.ResultValue = resultValue; return toReturn; } } public class FailResult<T> : Result<T> { public override bool IsSuccess { get { return false; } } protected FailResult() { } public static FailResult<T> New( ) { return new FailResult<T>(); } }`.

Comment: By having separate classes for successes and failures (`SuccessResult<T>` vs. `FailResult<T>`, both of which are `: Result<T>`'s), we can avoid having to have an unused field in `FailResult<T>` for a result-value.  That said, in C# it might potentially be a bit heavy-weight to use multiple types, plus making stuff `abstract`, to achieve that effect.

Comment: @Nat, The problem is that `T` will be different for the success and fail types. I.e., You end up having types derived from `Result<Stuff>` and a `Result<Error>` which are not assignment compatible.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: `T`'s the same in both cases.  The caller gets back a `: Result<T>`; that `: Result<T>` may be a `SuccessResult<T>` or `FailResult<T>`, depending on if the call succeeded/failed.  If it's a `SuccessResult<T>`, then it'll have a property `.ResultValue` with the result from the successful call; however, if it's a `FailResult<T>`, it won't have such a property.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: We can add some helper-extension-methods to make it convenient to use, too.  Though I'd speculate that a tuple-like solution would generally perform better in prior C#-environments, even if they may address storage that'd go unused in the event of a fail.

Comment: There're a few other ways such a thing could be constructed in C#.  I basically just wanted to point out that this could be done in C#, even if there wouldn't seem to be a strong call for it.

Comment: @Nat, the OP wants to return a `Stuff` class in case of success and an `Error` class in case of failure. So, what is `T` supposed to be?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: Ah, then an `Error`-property can be added to `FailResult<T>`.  Or we could make it `Result<T_ReturnValue, T_Error>`, with corresponding `SuccessResult<>` and `FailResult<>`.  (I'm hesitant to be too precise in describing it because there's really a bunch of ways that this could be done.)  In general, the idea'd be that we can avoid allocating space for unused fields (as in a tuple-like solution) by having an `abstract`-base with child-`class`'s that allocate space only for properties that they actually implement.

Answer (score 1):

Let's first consider two well-known extremes.

## `Option` types

An `Option` type is a type that encapsulates the notion that something may or may not exist. In languages that support *Closed Algebraic Sum Types* (aka *Discriminated Unions* aka *Tagged Unions* aka *Variant Types*), and `Option` type can be very simple:

```haskell
data Option a = None | Some a
```

That is, an `Option` of `a` is either a nullary data constructor representing nothingness or a wrapper around `a`.

This `Option` type has a couple of interesting properties: it can be viewed as a *collection* that has either exactly one element or is empty, i.e. similar to a list of length at-most one. What this means is that you can use all the power of the collections library, and all the knowledge you as a programmer have about collections to work with these `Option`s.

For example: you want to transform the value? Just `map` (in C# `Select`) the `Option`! You want to print it only if it exists? Just `foreach` it! You have nested computations all of which may or may not return a value and need to use the value of the previous computation? Just `flatMap` (in C# `SelectMany`) the `Options` and the result will either be the result of the entire computation if all of them return a value or `None` if any of them returns no value. In other words: `Option`s are composable!

Everything you know from how to handle collections transfers directly to `Option`s. Note that in the above examples, there was actually never any point where you would need an `if` statement or pattern matching or any other kind of conditional to check whether or not the value exists: if you `foreach` over an empty collection, then simply nothing happens, if you `map` or `flatMap` over an empty collection, you get an empty collection back. You can almost treat the `Option` as if it didn't exist, and it will just do the right thing.

More generally,`Option`s are not just collections, they are *monads* as well, meaning you can use all the power of monads. For example, in C#, monads support the LINQ Standard Query Operators and can be used with LINQ Query Expression Syntax. You could write something like this:

```csharp
var ultimateResult = 
    from res1 in ComputationThatMayOrMayNotReturnAResult()
    from res2 in AnotherComputation(res1)
    from res3 in YetAnotherComputation(res2)
    select res3;
```

And the result will either be `Some(res3)` or `None`.

`Option` can essentially replace any method that uses the `Try…` pattern, e.g. `int.TryParse(string)`.

Now, unfortunately, C# does not have Closed Algebraic Sum Types (although there are Github issues about that). But, it is possible to implement Algebraic Sum Types using nothing but simple rank-1 parametric polymorphism (aka Generics) and classical OO inheritance: the type becomes an abstract superclass and the data constructors become concrete subclasses.

In Scala, this looks something like this [Please forgive the large amount of Scala code, I don't really know C#]:

```scala
sealed trait Option[+A] {
  val isPresent: Boolean
  def getOrElse[B >: A](default: => B): B
  def foreach[B](f: A => B): Unit
  def map[B](f: A => B): Option[B]
}

case object None extends Option[Nothing] {
  override final val isPresent = false
  override def getOrElse[B](default: => B) = default
  override def foreach[B](f: Nothing => B) = ()
  override def map[B](f: Nothing => B): this.type = this
}

final case class Some[+A](value: A) extends Option[A] {
  override final val isPresent = true
  override def getOrElse[B >: A](default: => B): value.type = value
  override def foreach[B](f: A => B) = f(value)
  override def map[B](f: A => B): Some[B] = Some(f(value))
}

val twoPlusThree = Some(2).map(_ + 3)
twoPlusThree.foreach(println)
// 5

val ohOh = (None: Option[Int]).map(_ + 3)
ohOh.foreach(println)
// no output, since the `println` is never executed
```

[Scastie link](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/JoergWMittag/xr4cFjrdT5ueHBejo9yQ3A)

I chose to show a Scala example first, even though the question is about C#, because it is somewhat easier to see what is going on in the Scala example. (For example, C# does not have upper bounds for generic type parameters, so we have to use `A` as the parameter type for the default value in `getOrElse`, which is however a contravariant position, which in turn means that `Option` cannot be covariant in `A`, and so on. Also, C# doesn't have a bottom type (type that is a subtype of all types), so we cannot have a single `None` object, we need a separate `None<T>` object for each `T`, and so on.)

In C#, this could look somewhat like this:

```csharp
var twoPlusThree = new Some<int>(2).Select(i => i + 3);
twoPlusThree.ForEach(System.Console.WriteLine);
// 5

var ohOh = new None<int>().Select(i => i + 3);
ohOh.ForEach(System.Console.WriteLine);
// no output, since the `WriteLine` is never executed

interface Option<T> /* : IEnumerable<T>, … */ where T : notnull
{
    bool IsPresent { get; }
    T GetOrElse(T defaultValue);
    void ForEach(Action<T> action);
    Option<U> Select<U>(Func<T, U> f) where U : notnull;
}

readonly record struct None<T> : Option<T> where T : notnull
{
    public bool IsPresent { get => false; }
    public T GetOrElse(T defaultValue) => defaultValue;
    public void ForEach(Action<T> action) { }
    public Option<U> Select<U>(Func<T, U> f) where U : notnull => new None<U>();
    // In reality, you would probably have a factory method that caches one `None` for each `U`
}

readonly record struct Some<T>(T value) : Option<T> where T : notnull
{
    public bool IsPresent { get => true; }
    public T GetOrElse(T defaultValue) => value;
    public void ForEach(Action<T> action) => action(value);
    public Option<U> Select<U>(Func<T, U> f) where U : notnull => new Some<U>(f(value));
}
```

(Obviously, a real-world implementation would have all the `IEnumerable` methods, also `IComparable` would be a good idea, and we would implement Serialization and Deconstruction / Pattern Matching, etc.)

As you can see, it is structurally very similar to the Scala code. The main differences are:

- The Scala version is *closed*, you cannot add any further subclasses to it. (`sealed` in Scala means "can only be extended within the same compilation unit", whereas `final` means "cannot be extended at all", i.e. like `sealed` in C#. Since `Option` is `sealed`, it can only be extended within the same compilation unit, and the only two templates that extend it are `Some` and `None`, both of which are `final`.)
- The Scala version is covariant.
- The Scala version only has a single `None` value. (`Nothing` is a *bottom* type, i.e. it is a subtype of every type. And since `Option` is covariant, `Option[Nothing]` is a subtype of every `Option[T]` for all `T`. Therefore, a single `None` can be used wherever an `Option[T]` is expected.)

## `Either` types

So, what we had now was a type that encapsulates the notion that something either is there or it isn't there. In other words, it either is some type or it is nothing.

The other extreme is something that can be either one type or another type. This kind of type is called an `Either` type. It, too, can be easily expressed as an algebraic sum type:

```haskell
data Either a b = Left a | Right b
```

This can be implemented in the same way as `Option` using inheritance:

```scala
sealed trait Either[+A, +B] {
  val isLeft: Boolean
  val isRight: Boolean
  def getLeftOrElse[C >: A](default: => C): C
  def getRightOrElse[C >: B](default: => C): C
  def either[C](f: A => C)(g: B => C): C
}

final case class Left[+A](value: A) extends Either[A, Nothing] {
  override final val isLeft = true
  override final val isRight = false
  override def getLeftOrElse[C >: A](default: => C): value.type = value
  override def getRightOrElse[C](default: => C) = default
  override def either[C](f: A => C)(g: Nothing => C) = f(value)
}

final case class Right[+B](value: B) extends Either[Nothing, B] {
  override final val isLeft = false
  override final val isRight = true
  override def getLeftOrElse[C](default: => C) = default
  override def getRightOrElse[C >: B](default: => C): value.type = value
  override def either[C](f: Nothing => C)(g: B => C) = g(value)
}

val s: Either[String, Int] = Left("Hello")
val i: Either[String, Int] = Right(23)

println(s.either(_.length)(_ * 2))
// 5
println(i.either(_.length)(_ * 2))
// 46
```

[Scastie link](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/JoergWMittag/51ZYmGJXTjSniAAXLJVsjg/3)

Scala has some other syntactic niceties that we can use. For example, generic types with exactly two type parameters can be written `A Foo B` instead of `Foo[A, B]`. So, if we rename our `Either` to `Or`, we could write `A Or B` as the type, which reads really nice. In fact, `|` is a legal identifier like any other in Scala, so we could also name the trait `|` and write `A | B`.

In C#, it would look roughly like this:

```csharp
Either<string, int> s = new Left<string, int>("Hello");
Either<string, int> i = new Right<string, int>(23);

System.Console.WriteLine(s.Either(x => x.Length, x => x * 2));
// 5
System.Console.WriteLine(i.Either(x => x.Length, x => x * 2));
// 46

interface Either<A, B> where A : notnull where B : notnull
{
    bool IsLeft { get; }
    bool IsRight { get; }
    A GetLeftOrElse(A defaultValue);
    B GetRightOrElse(B defaultValue);
    C Either<C>(Func<A, C> f, Func<B, C> g) where C : notnull;
}

readonly record struct Left<A, B>(A value) : Either<A, B> where A : notnull where B : notnull
{
    public bool IsLeft { get => true; }
    public bool IsRight { get => false; }
    public A GetLeftOrElse(A defaultValue) => value;
    public B GetRightOrElse(B defaultValue) => defaultValue;
    public C Either<C>(Func<A, C> f, Func<B, C> g) where C : notnull => f(value);
}

readonly record struct Right<A, B>(B value) : Either<A, B> where A : notnull where B : notnull
{
    public bool IsLeft { get => false; }
    public bool IsRight { get => true; }
    public A GetLeftOrElse(A defaultValue) => defaultValue;
    public B GetRightOrElse(B defaultValue) => value;
    public C Either<C>(Func<A, C> f, Func<B, C> g) where C : notnull => g(value);
}
```

(Obviously, a real-world implementation would implement Serialization and Deconstruction / Pattern Matching, etc.)

Unfortunately, the `Either` type does not have the nice monadic properties of `Option`. (Unless you "bias" it to one side, that is.) So, we can't implement `IEnumerable`, `Select`, `SelectMany`, `ForEach`, and friends. We have to either implement everything twice, or always pass both alternatives. So, for example instead of `ForEach` we would have `ExecuteIfLeft(Action<A>)` and `ExecuteIfRight(Action<B>)`, or `ExecuteEither(Action<A>, Action<B>)`, and similar for `Select`, and so on.

This is essentially a Discriminated Union implemented in a language that doesn't support them.

## `Error` types

Halfway in between `Option` (which only supports one type or the absence of a value) and `Either` (which completely generically supports two types) lies the `Error` type, which supports either a value or an error. You can think of it as a *biased `Either`*, where one type is fixed to be an error type (`type Error[A] = Either[A, Throwable]`). Because it is biased to one side, it satisfies all the monadic properties and can implement the LINQ Standard Query Operators (meaning `Select`, `SelectMany`, `ForEach`, etc. all prefer one side).

The semantics are similar to `Option`: it either returns the result of the whole computation chain, or it returns the first error and aborts the chain.

```scala
import scala.util.control.NonFatal

sealed trait Try[+A] {
  val isSuccess: Boolean
  val isFailure: Boolean
  def getOrElse[B >: A](default: => B): B
  def foreach[B](f: A => B): Unit
  def map[B](f: A => B): Try[B]
  def flatMap[B](f: A => Try[B]): Try[B]
}

final case class Success[+A](value: A) extends Try[A] {
  override final val isSuccess = true
  override final val isFailure = false
  override def getOrElse[B >: A](default: => B): value.type = value
  override def foreach[B](f: A => B) = f(value)
  override def map[B](f: A => B): Success[B] = Success(f(value))
  override def flatMap[B](f: A => Try[B]) = try f(value) catch { case NonFatal(e) => Failure(e) }
}

final case class Failure[+A, E <: Throwable](ex: E) extends Try[A] {
  override final val isSuccess = false
  override final val isFailure = true
  override def getOrElse[B](default: => B) = default
  override def foreach[B](f: A => B) = ()
  override def map[B](f: A => B) = this.asInstanceOf[Try[B]]
  override def flatMap[B](f: A => Try[B]) = this.asInstanceOf[Try[B]]
}

object Try {
  def apply[A](f: => A): Try[A] =
    try Success(f) catch {
      case NonFatal(e) => Failure(e)
    }
}
```

[Scastie link](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/JoergWMittag/1O8b8rIvRCKrvVedQGu0fw/19)

And again in C#

```csharp
interface Try<T> where T : notnull
{
    bool IsSuccess { get; }
    bool IsFailure { get; }
    T GetOrElse(T defaultValue);
    void ForEach(Action<T> action);
    Try<U> Select<U>(Func<T, U> f) where U : notnull;
}

readonly record struct Success<T>(T value) : Try<T> where T : notnull
{
    public bool IsSuccess { get => true; }
    public bool IsFailure { get => false; }
    public T GetOrElse(T defaultValue) => value;
    public void ForEach(Action<T> action) => action(value);
    public Try<U> Select<U>(Func<T, U> f) where U : notnull => new Success<U>(f(value));
}

readonly record struct Failure<T, E>(E ex) : Try<T> where T : notnull where E : Exception
{
    public bool IsSuccess { get => false; }
    public bool IsFailure { get => true; }
    public T GetOrElse(T defaultValue) => defaultValue;
    public void ForEach(Action<T> action) { }
    public Try<U> Select<U>(Func<T, U> f) where U : notnull => this as Try<U>;
}
```

I believe between these three examples, we have covered all of your use cases (two different types, a type or an error) as well as another common case (value that might exist or not).

In all three cases, we can use pattern matching, as you suggested. But actually, especially for `Option` and `Try`, it is even better to treat them either as collections (using `ForEach`, `Select`, `SelectMany`, `Where`, and so on) or as monads (in LINQ Query Expressions), because they just do the right thing by themselves without the need for any sort of conditional (whether that be an `if` statement or pattern matching).

All three of these are essentially your proposal #2, while also facilitating #3, but with well-known names and reusable, general semantics. In fact, many languages ship these three types in their standard libraries, e.g. Scala: [`Option`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html), [`Either`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Either.html), [`Try`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Try.html). Even Java now ships with [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html), although unfortunately, this one does *not* implement the collection API.

Comment: A potential problem using structs inheriting from an interface is that it will likely cause boxing. I think it is more common in .Net to reduce inheritance and use a internal flag to indicate the state. See [random github example](https://github.com/nlkl/Optional/blob/master/src/Optional/Option_Maybe.cs)

Answer (score -1):

C# also has structures which are arguably simpler than classes, since they are copied more or less directly by value rather than allocated (presumably in the heap) and passed by reference.

C# also has several types included in the library, namely Tuple<type1,type2> (and Tuple<type1,type2,type3>, etc..), which means you can declare a return type as a struct containing two members without even having to declare a new or custom struct type, if you are willing to settle for non-descript field names like Item1 and Item2.

Newer C# also has simpler tuple syntax and destructuring assignment.

Comment: Tuples are arguably "the wrong way round", however. What you want is a *sum type*, but tuples are *product types*. They are exactly the dual of what you need.

Comment: @JörgWMittag yes agreed.  If you want to return error vs. value, but, if you want to do what the OP said in the title (return multiple results), then product types...

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that. In the question *body*, the OP writes (**bold** emphasis mine) "It can return `Stuff` **or** `Error`" and "Important for me is that code is […] robust (i.e. **no** weird cases when someone can **return both success and result by mistake** etc.)." which to me implies that the OP is looking for "either / or", whereas the title "return **multiple** results" implies "and".

Comment: @JörgWMittag, yes, hopefully this discussion will help future readers clarify the difference.

Comment: I've skipped depicting tuples here as container object are superior, because in implementation you can guard aganist case of multiple values, setting both at once etc. I think container object is superior here.